# Tensor in "Three manifolds with positive Ricci curvature"

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

Seemly, in Hamilton's paper, tensor is a map like
$$
T: \mathfrak X(M) \times \cdots \times \mathfrak X(M) \rightarrow \mathfrak X(M)
$$
where $\mathfrak X(M)$ is vector fields. It does not like the definition on do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. But I think they are equal. But if so,  there should be
$$
\partial_v T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right) =\partial_v\left(T_{jk}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right)
=v^h\partial _hT_{jk}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + v^hT_{jk}^i\partial _h\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
$$
where $\partial _h\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} =\nabla_{\partial_h} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ according to do Carmo's notation. Why does this term vanish ?

PS:  Assume $T:\mathfrak X(M) \times \mathfrak X(M) \rightarrow \mathfrak X(M)$ is bilinear. $\partial_i=\frac{\partial }{\partial {x^i}}.$  In my view,
$$
(\nabla_vT)(\partial_i, \partial _j) = v(T(\partial_i, \partial _j))-T(\nabla_v\partial_i, \partial _j) 
-
T(\partial_i, \nabla_v\partial _j)  \\
=v^h(\partial_hT_{ij}^k) \partial_k -v^h\Gamma_{hi}^aT_{aj}^k\partial_k-
v^h\Gamma_{hj}^aT_{ia}^k \partial_k
$$
where I use the definition in 102th page of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. Obviously, it is not same with the last red line.

> [image]

Comment: I think you should read it $\color{red}{(}\partial_v T\color{red}{)}(\partial_i,\partial_j)$ and not $\partial_v \color{red}{(}T(\partial_i,\partial_j)\color{red}{)}$.

Comment: Looks like they are using $\partial_v$ for the covariant derivative (instead of $\nabla_v$, which is more common nowadays). Can you confirm that?

Comment: @ArcticChar  I think $\partial_v$ is $\nabla_v$.  Since in this paper, they call $\partial_i$ as covariant derivative.

Comment: @C.F.G  I read it as $\color{red}{(}\partial_v T\color{red}{)}(\partial_i,\partial_j)$, and add my calculation  above, but it still be wrong...

Comment: You are confusing yourself. Your $\partial _h$ in $\partial _h T_{ij}^k$ is the usual partial derivative, which is not $\nabla_h T_{ij}^k$.

Comment: @ArcticChar  Sorry, I still don't know where is my mistake. Could you detailly talk it ? Thanks very much.

Comment: It would seem the author is using the notation (for the components) $\partial_h T_{j\,k}^{\,i}=\frac{\partial T_{j\,k}^{\,i}}{\partial x^h}-\Gamma_{j\,h}^{\, m}T_{m\,k}^{\,i}-\Gamma_{k\,h}^{\,m}T_{j\,m}^{\,i}$. At least that is my interpretation since then it is consistent with the notion of tangent vectors as directional derivatives on scalar fields $t(f)=t^a\nabla_af$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (I used $\nabla_v$ instead of $\partial _v$)

\begin{align} (\nabla_v T)\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) &=v^h(\partial_hT_{ij}^k) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} -v^h\Gamma_{hi}^aT_{aj}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}-
v^h\Gamma_{hj}^aT_{ia}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\\
&= v^h \left( \partial_h T_{ij}^k - \Gamma_{hi}^aT_{aj}^k-
\Gamma_{hj}^aT_{ia}^k\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}
\end{align}

And that's correct. This is also the same as

$$ (\nabla_v T)\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = v^h (\nabla_{\partial_h} T)\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = v^h \nabla_h T_{ij}^k \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}$$

since

$$ \nabla_h T_{ij}^k = \partial_h T_{ij}^k - \Gamma_{hi}^aT_{aj}^k-
\Gamma_{hj}^aT_{ia}^k$$

by definition of $\nabla$.